# DateTime method in salesforce

Tags: apex

In my code, I am writing a query where I can give start date as midnight of some date.

So, I have written like below :

```
DateTime startofDate = DateTime.newInstance(dummyObj.StartDateA__c,Time.newInstance(24, 0, 0,0));
```

// `dummyObj.StartDateA__c` is a date field.

I checked in debug log it is coming like below :

```
CreatedDate >= 2014-04-01T12:00:00Z
```

So, my question is what'd be the value of Time.newInstance method, so that it will consider the time starting from midnight.

Answer (score 3):

> The answer to your question depends on which timezone you are in .The debug logs will always show time in GMT and the method **DateTime.newInstance** always returns constructed date time in your local time zone .

So I believe its calculating GMT equivalent of local date and time constructed from your expression .

Also below two expressions are same in case thats causing confusion

```
system.debug('*****'+Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0,0));//*****00:00:00.000Z
system.debug('*****'+Time.newInstance(24, 0, 0,0));//*****00:00:00.000Z
```